# Should I always declare char array bigger than my string is?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, char

So I know that you should declare char arrays to be one element bigger than the word you want to put there because of the `\0` that has to be at the end, but what about char arrays that I don't want to use as words?

I'm currently writing a program in which i store an array of keyboard letters that have some function assigned to them. Should I still end this array with `\0`?

Comment: Only if you plan to use it as a c-string.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Pick the one you use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is probably not necessary.

A null terminator is not a requirement for arrays of `char`; it is a requirement for "C-strings", things that you intend to use as unitary blobs of data, particularly if you intend to pass them to C API functions. It's the conventional way that the "length" of the string is determined.

But if you just want a collection of `char`s to use independently then knock yourself out.

**We cannot see your code, but it sounds to me like you don't want or need it in this case.**

Answer (score 5):

The array should have, at least, the same number of elements as the data you will put there. So, if:

- you don't need the '\0'
- you won't place it there
- you won't use routines that will depend on an '\0' to tell you the array size

... you are good with not using the trailing '\0'

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C++, you should probably just use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` or even `std::array<char>` and not worry about terminators.

Comment: This right here! OPs question is an interesting one for C, but C++ has better-fitting and more expressive tools.

Comment: `std::string` as a replacement for C-strings, sure. But for a simple `char[]` without C-string semantics, I feel like suggesting `std::array<char, N>` (while noble) only moves the goalposts. Because we still have to ask whether the final element ought to be a null, or at least we have to ask that to the same degree that we have to ask it about a `char[]`. Well, maybe a little less since it won't decay to a `char*` without you asking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I figure if OP was about to pass this array to any C string functions, using standard containers would at least cause a type error.

Comment: Fair enough I guess

Answer (score 3):

It depends on usage. If you want to use it not as just byte array, but as c-string with probably usage of some standard string algorithms (`strcmp` and so on), or output to the stream - your array should ends with `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to do, if you are trying to define a *C-style string then, you need the terminator since the C-library won't be able to calculate the size of the string and other things if you don't*...

In C++, though, the size of the string is already stored inside the `std::string` class along with the dynamic array of `char`s...

But if you just need a free container for storing characters where you don't need it to do *C-string-like* things... You are free to do:

```
char hello[128]; // 128 elements, do anything with them...
```

Without the terminator...

In your case, you are **storing** values, not creating a *string*, and you won't probably treat it as a string either, so doing it **without** the null-terminator, suffices...

Answer (score 0):

`\0` will certainly make it easier when wanting to use functions like `strlen`, `strcmp`, `strcat`and the like, but is not required.

An aside - We have an entire enterprise code base built upon strings (char arrays) with no null terminators in the database. Works just fine.